How to reduce PCL file size while converting pdf to pcl using ghost script?
I am converting a PDF file to a pcl format using ghostscript. Size of pdf file is 70kb but when I convert to PCL file then size becomes very large like 700kb for 300 resolution and 2mb for 600 resolution. I have tried many options with gs command to optimize the size but somehow did not succeed. Can someone give me any hint on what should I try?
I've tried many gs command but not succeed.

The PDF file probably (but we can't tell because you haven't supplied it) contains content which cannot be preserved in PCL. When that happens the content is rendered to a bitmap, and that is what ends up in the PCL file. Increasing size with resolution (as you state happens) is exactly what will happen in this case. There is nothing you can do about it, except alter the PDF file so that it doesn't have content which is impossible to preserve in a PCL file.
